# @remoteAction unexpected token: 'User'

Tags: apex, remote-action

This is the error I get:
unexpected token: 'User' (Line: 6, Column: 2)

```
global with sharing class Chat_Enterprise_PreChatController {

    @remoteAction
    global static Boolean updateContactDetails {

        User user = [select Id , ContactId from User where id=:userInfo.getUserId() ];
        if(user.ContactId != null){
            Contact con = [SELECT Account_Name__c,Email,FirstName,Id,LastName FROM Contact where Id=:user.ContactId ];

            if(con!=null)
            {
                return con;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Its a method. Add `()` after `updateContactDetails`

Comment: @Reshma Sorry I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Remoteaction` is denoting a method always. You have missed `()` enclosing parenthesis.

This is how a method is declaring.

```
[public | private | protected | global] [override] [static] ***data_type*** method_name 
(input parameters) 
{
// The body of the method
}
```

Change this line

```
global static Boolean updateContactDetails {
```

to

```
global static Boolean updateContactDetails() {
```

See more on [Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm).

Comment: hahah I missed it!